# Can you check for a null array in logstash?

Tags: arrays, logstash, logstash-grok

I've got a mutate that is adding/merging the tags array.

```
if [context][tags] {
  mutate {
    merge => [ "tags", "context[tags]" ]
    remove_field => [ "context[tags]" ]
  }
}
```

The problem is, in cases where `[tags]` is null to begin with I end up with an array of...
`[ nil, 'something1', 'something2']`

Is there a way to test `[tags]` for null before I merge, and if so then replace rather than merge?

Comment: It seems your question answers itself by example... have you tried `if [tags]` nested inside the `if [context][tags]`?

Answer (score 1):

Alcanzar had it. Revised code that works:

```
if [context][tags] {
    if [tags] {
        mutate {
            merge => [ "tags", "context[tags]" ]
            remove_field => [ "context[tags]" ]
        }
    } else {
        mutate {
            rename => [ "context[tags]", "tags" ]
            remove_field => [ "context[tags]" ]
        }
    }
}
```

It turns out, I couldn't use `replace` to switch `context[tags]` to `tags`, but `rename` worked fine.